# one to one relationship JPA with multipartfile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I apparently don't know how to do a oneToOne relationship with JPA.

Article entity

```
@Entity
public class Article {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String title;

private String content;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "files_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private MultipartFile file;
```

File Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
public class DBFile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    private String fileName;

    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "files")
    private Article article;
```

Terminal

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.test.webservices.article.Article.file references an unknown entity: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile
```

I tried to change String by Long to dbfileEntity but I have some trouble to build the uri's path after... I don't understand why it doesn't work since I used @Table annotation.
Could someone explain me?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo. Here you're saying you're mapping by `files`:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "files")
private Article article;
```

Where the field name is `file`:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "files_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private MultipartFile file;
```

You should fix the `mappedBy` property:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "file")
private Article article;
```

Also the type is wrong, it should be:

```
private DBFile file;
```

Comment: Good game, it works! But now I have the same problem has when I tried to upload only the file... 
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------096279328385565755529413;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Thx so much!

Comment: @JeanReno hard to say by looking at that error, I would suggest creating a new question for that